# How can I record the user's LOCAL date time in parse server?

Tags: swift, parse-server

I am using parse-server and swift 4 working on a simple app where users can post images and I would like to include a user friendly label for when past posts were created.  Similar to how Facebook and others say things like "Today at 5:06pm", "Yesterday at 2:00pm", or "Wed, Feb 13 2018".

It is easy enough to write out the current date to a parse-server object but each time I do this it records it in UTC and I don't see anywhere that it records the Timezone that the post was created from.  I guess I could use UTC and always convert to the user's local timezone when I present the label.  But if they are on vacation and posted something at noon in London I wouldn't want them to look back on the post and have it look like they did it in the middle of the night.

Would greatly appreciate some help, something like a snippet that records the date in parse-server but KEEPS the timezone to the local one.  Is the proper way to record a second column with timezone on parse?  If so, how would I then apply that when presenting in swift?

I had this snippet for printing out the local Date/Time but I don't see how I can post this to parse as a date...

```
// Log users local date/time
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
let dateString = "Current date is: \(dateFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date))"
print(String(dateString))
//Time
let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
timeFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
let timeString = "Current time is: \(timeFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date))"
print(String(timeString))

let dataLog = PFObject(className:"DataLog")
dataLog["Time"] = "Imagine I put a time here"
dataLog["playerName"] = "DanLovesK_02"
dataLog["cheatMode"] = false
dataLog["localTS"] = Date()
dataLog.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
    if (success) {
        print("Successfull")
    } else {
        print("Dan is Bad")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go for the second column with time zone

Comment: I second what @Geru suggests, if really you want to circumvent the 'vacation' problem, store the posting timezone and always in UTC. Never store dates not in UTC. And always compute in the reader's timezone compared to the date / time of posting. Also, you probably are over engineering :)